# Self-Made LinkedList need clarification

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have to make a LinkedList that uses

```
struct infoType
{
int ID;
int X;
double Y;
};
```

so I have this, I set up this LinkedList to take elements but I don't know how to make it sort through the list using the ID, search with X.

I think what my professor wants is that it will take an element, Y, and that element with be assigned with an ID and with X. Y would be the a random number generated with an RNG. and it has to be able to Add the element, which I created through AddFirst, remove, added through removeFirst. and then print he list, which would be added with a getList method.

```
    import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class MyLinkedList {
    private Node first;
    private int ID;
    private int X;
    private double Y;
    private int Size;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
        ID = 0;
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;

    }

    public Object getFirst()
    {
        if (first == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return first.data;
    }

    public Object removeFirst()
    {
        if (first == null) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object element = first.data;
        first = first.next;
        return element;
    }

    public void addFirst(Object element)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = first;
        first = newNode;
    }

    public ListIterator listIterator()
    {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    class Node
    {
        public Object data;
        public Node next;
    }

    class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
    {
        private Node position;
        private Node previous;

        public LinkedListIterator()
        {
            position = null;
            previous = null;
        }



    public Object next()
    {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        previous = position;

        if (position == null)
            position = first;
        else
            position = position.next;
            return position.data;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (position == null)
            return first != null;
        else
            return position.next != null;
    }


    public void add (Object element)
    {
        if (position == null)
        {
            addFirst(element);
            position = first;
        }

        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = position.next;
            position.next = newNode;
            position = newNode;
        }
        previous = position;
    }

    public void remove ()
    {
        if (previous == position)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

        if (position == first)
        {
            removeFirst();
        }
        else
        {
            previous.next = position.next;
        }
        position = previous;
    }
    public void set (Object element)
    {
        if (position == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        position.data = element;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public int nextIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public Object previous() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int previousIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Size;
    }

}
```

Here is MyLinkedListTester

```
public class MyLinkedListTester {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + list.size());



        int a = 2;
        int b = 5;
        double c = 7;


        list.addFirst(a,b,c);


        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + list.size());
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated since at this point im running in circles, and I cant see my professor till tomorrow, Id like to make more headway today. Thank you

Comment: do not forget to increase the size by adding  `Size++;` an item to delete an item decrease `Size-- ;`

Comment: Ah ok that helped adjust the Size when i ran the test, so thats one step out of the way. Thank you